# How to efficiently pull data out of a huge api with multiple pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux

I am currently using an API to create a React Redux application. My problem is I am confused about how to efficiently use the data as the API has more than 14470 "pages" to navigate around. My main goal is to display certain items in the API based on key value pair. For example I would say I want to display a category in the API based on a certain key value pair such as "highestRating" and want to map through the API to find out the five items with the highestRating, how would I be able to do this efficiently?

What I have tried so far is looping to get the entire API available to me but then I get stuck with my current task at hand.

```
export const fetchHighestRating = () => async dispatch => {
  let data = [];
  let morePagesAvailable = true;
  let currentPage = 0; 
  while (morePagesAvailable) {
    currentPage++;
    const response = await api.get(
      `/api?page%5Blimit%5D=10&page%5Boffset%5D=${currentPage}`
    );
    data = [...data , response]; 
    morePagesAvailable = currentPage < 17471;
  }

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_HIGHEST, payload: data });
};
```

Comment: A common practice you'll see (for example, in SQL) is called indexing, where you run this code once every time the data changes to generate a sorted list which is sorted by the key you want (highestRating, for example), and then you just pull from the sorted results later. In this case, you would just grab the first 5 items from that sorted list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a javascript problem, it is database. You should run query directly in database to test response speed and decide what to do next, including:

- Sharding
- Indexing
- Optimize config of DB
- ....

Any above required research in type of DB you are using, the current situation of DB so there is no exactly answer now!